# Echo current URL id in textfield in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a category,And I need to create a subcategory of that.
When i tried to create the subcategory i have a field called category Name which should preloaded with the name of category which i wish to create subcategory.

how can i achieve this..

My controller

```
public function actionCreate($id)
{
    $model=new SubCategory;
    $mode = Category::model()->findAll();
    $mode_1=$this->loadModel1($id);






    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['SubCategory']))

    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['SubCategory'];

        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('create','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

And the form

```
    <?php
/* @var $this SubCategoryController */
/* @var $model SubCategory */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */
?>

<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'sub-category-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>
<?php 
    $category_id = $_GET['id'];
    $category = Category::model()->findByAttributes(array('id' => $category_id));

    // echo '<pre>';print_r($category);'</pre>';
 ?>
    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'category_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'category_id',
        array('class'=>'form-control','style'=>'width:300px;')); ?>

        <?php echo $form->error($model,'category_id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'subcategory_name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'subcategory_name',array('class'=>'form-control','style'=>'width:300px;')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'subcategory_name'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save',array('class' => 'btn btn-default')); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->

<div style="width: 97%; margin: auto;" >


<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'fav-category-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    //'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        // 'id',
        //'favcategory',
        array('header'=>'#','htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'60px'),
            'value'=>'$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + ($row+1)',
        ), 

        //'id', 
        //'category_id',
        array(
            'name' => 'category_id',
            'value' => '$data->category->categoryname',
             //'filter'=> CHtml::listData(Category::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'categoryname')), 'categoryid', 'categoryname')
        ),
        'subcategory_name',
         array(
                'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'110px'),
                'template' => '{update}{delete}',
                'buttons' => array( 
                        'update'=>array(
                             'imageUrl' =>false,
                             'label' => '', 
                             'options' => array('title'=>'update','class'=>'btn btn-info btn-xs fa fa-pencil-square-o'),
                                ),    
                        'delete'=>array(
                            'imageUrl' =>false,
                            'label' => 'delete', 
                            'options' => array('title'=>'view','class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-xs'),
                        ),

                )
            ),
    ),
'itemsCssClass'=>'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover',
        'pagerCssClass'=>'pagination', 
        'pager'=>array( 'header' => '','lastPageLabel'=>'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>','firstPageLabel'=>'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>','prevPageLabel'=>'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>','nextPageLabel'=>'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>','header' => '','cssFile' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/css/pager.css','htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pagination'),'selectedPageCssClass'=>'active'),


)); ?>








</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see category model `$category` getting loaded in the form.

```
$category = Category::model()->findByAttributes(array('id' => $category_id));
```

And if `id` in `category` table is primary key, then I suggest, just for simplicity:

```
$category = Category::model()->findByPk($category_id);
```

Now I am guessing you may want that in textField which will be disabled.

So use `textField()` of `CActiveForm` in the form, something like:

```
$form->textField($category, 'name', array('disabled' => 'disabled'));
```

textField [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#textField-detail)

**Note: The second parameter must be the attribute name, I have assumed `name`.**

Also I don't see the use of the following two lines in `actionCreate()`. I mean, the variable `$mode` and `$mode_1` are not used anywhere in that action.

```
$mode = Category::model()->findAll();
$mode_1=$this->loadModel1($id);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer...When i tried the answer it shows that category filed cannot be blank....I tried to disable the validation...but it failed....What to do now???

Comment: `category filed cannot be blank` it means the field is required to be filled when it is saved. Check `rules()` in your model.